# Get rid of page number in top right corner; keep page number in bottom center

Tags: page-numbering

The requirements for my thesis are giving me a headache! I've finally got everything except for one issue: I need to get rid of the arabic page numbers at the top right of the page starting in Chapter 1.

Here's the relevant code (the very bottom is the problem - the last three lines):

```
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{roman}

% A B S T R A C T
% ---------------
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\begin{center}\textbf{ABSTRACT}\end{center}

\input{Abstract.tex} 

\clearpage

\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{page}{4}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% S T A T E M E N T  OF  C O N T R I B U T I O N S  P A G E
% -------------------------------
 \noindent
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contributions} 
 \begin{center}
 \textbf{STATEMENT OF CONTRIBUTIONS}
 \end{center}
 \bigskip 
 \noindent
\input{contributions.tex} 

\clearpage

% D E D I C A T I O N
% -------------------

\begin{center}\textbf{DEDICATION}\end{center}

\begin{center}
Dedication
\end{center}

\newpage

% A C K N O W L E D G E M E N T S
% -------------------------------

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{center}\textbf{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}\end{center}

%Acknowledgements will go here.

\clearpage


% C O M I C
% ---------
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Comic}
\begin{center}

\vspace*{0.75cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{machine_learning_xkcd_1838.png} 
\\
\vspace*{0.5cm}
Reprinted from \href{http://xkcd.com/1838}{xkcd.com}. 
\end{center}

\newpage

% T A B L E   O F   C O N T E N T S
% ---------------------------------

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% 
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage} 
}

\renewcommand\contentsname{\hfill\normalsize\textbf{CONTENTS}\hfill}

\tableofcontents

\newpage 

% L I S T   O F   T A B L E S
% ---------------------------
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
    \@starttoc{lot}%
    }
\makeatother
\begin{center}\textbf{LIST OF TABLES}\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

\begin{center}
\listoftables
\end{center}

\phantomsection     % allows hyperref to link to the correct page

\newpage %Sept 24

% L I S T   O F   F I G U R E S
% -----------------------------
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    }
\makeatother
\begin{center}\textbf{LIST OF FIGURES}\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\begin{center}
\listoffigures
\end{center}

\phantomsection     % allows hyperref to link to the correct page
\newpage

% P R E F A C E
% -------------
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Preface}}
\begin{center}
\textbf{{PREFACE}}
\end{center}
\input{preface.tex}  
\pagestyle{plain}
\cleardoublepage

% Change page numbering back to Arabic numerals

\fancyhr{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\cfoot{\thepage}
```

How can I suppress the page number in the top right?

Comment: Can you provide a more comprehensive example that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Comment: @Werner, I understand the value of a MWE; however no, I can't do that here. I would have to give you my whole thesis.

Comment: That's not likely. Add `\usepackage{lipsum}` to your preamble, remove `\input{contributions.tex}` and replace it with `\lipsum[1-5]` (or something similar to that). We just want all the detail up to where the problem is... are you using a special `\documentclass`?

Comment: If you are using a university specific document class, it should already have the page numbers on the bottom (as required), which means you must have added a `\pagestyle` command (copied from some random template).

Comment: I solved the problem using a terrible hack: I put a blank square overtop of the offending page number in Adobe Acrobat, then submitted the thesis. The library accepted it, so the problem is "solved".

Comment: This might be fixed by setting `\thispagestyle{plain}` on the affected page.  More can't be said without a compilable example.